# Conditional Ordering By Value in SQL expression wont effect the LINQ Results using SQLite.Net-PCL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

pure sql (in sqlite) is this:

```
select * from Employees order by case WorkDay
         WHEN 'MON' then 0
         WHEN 'TUE' then 1
         WHEN 'WED' then 2
         WHEN 'THU' then 3 
         WHEN 'FRI' then 4 END
```

result in a sql editor is okay and as expected

```
id| FullName   | Department| WorkDay
7   Frank Bone   C Block     MON
8   Frank Bone   D Block     TUE
6   Frank Bone   A Block     FRI
9   Frank Bone   E Block     FRI
```

and C# code using SQLite.Net-PCL (Universal Windows Platform)

```
 var rows = 
     conn.Query<Employees>("select * from Employees order by case WorkDay
                            WHEN 'MON' then 0 
                            WHEN 'TUE' then 1
                            WHEN 'WED' then 2 
                            WHEN 'THU' then 3 
                            WHEN 'FRI' then 4 END").ToList();

      //rows.ForEach(x => { listBox1.Add(x); }); rows appears in wrong/weird order in debug mode. this line not important and not the cause of wrong order.
```

rows appears in a weird/wrong order

I got this rows in a wrong order. Do you know what causes this weird order?

```
id| FullName   | Department| WorkDay
6   Frank Bone   A Block     FRI
7   Frank Bone   C Block     MON
9   Frank Bone   E Block     FRI
8   Frank Bone   D Block     TUE
```

extra note: Model of table class (EF?)

```
public class Employees
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public string WorkDay { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

define enum , and do rest as given below

```
 [Flags] enum DayEnum { MON=0, TUE= 1, WED= 2, THU= 3, FRI = 4};

public class Employees
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string WorkDay { get; set    ; }
        public DayEnum DayNO{ get; set; }
    }

var employees = conn.Query<Employees>("select * from Employees");
var rows = (from e in employees
           select new Employee() {
                id  =e.id
                FullName   = e.FullName
                Department = e.Department
                WorkDay = e.WorkDay
                DayNO = (DayEnum ) Enum.Parse(typeof(DayEnum ), e.WorkDay)
            }).OrderBy(e=>e.DayNO );
```

---

As per you comment seems like problem with library , one work around is

add new property WorkDayNo

```
public class Employees
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string WorkDay { get; set; }
    public string WorkDayNo { get; set; }
}
```

do query like this

```
var rows = 
     conn.Query<Employees>("select *, (case WorkDay
                                WHEN 'MON' then 0 
                                WHEN 'TUE' then 1
                                WHEN 'WED' then 2 
                                WHEN 'THU' then 3 
                                WHEN 'FRI' then 4 END) as WorkDayNo from Employees").OrderBy(e=> e.WorkDayNo).ToList();
```

---

Can you please try query as below

```
select id, FullName, Department,WorkDay from
(select *, (case WorkDay
                            WHEN 'MON' then 0 
                            WHEN 'TUE' then 1
                            WHEN 'WED' then 2 
                            WHEN 'THU' then 3 
                            WHEN 'FRI' then 4 END) as workdayno from Employees) d  order by  workdayno
```

Comment: sql editor throws syntax error Mr Pranay. no "in or from" in somewhere before subquery?. the sql code in My question works in sqleditor as expected. but in C# codebehind order rows result becames wrong ordersomehow .

Comment: @KursatTurkay - i update query can you please try that, i forgot to include END

Comment: > near "select": syntax error (Im trying to find error)

Comment: wow  adding keyword "from" worked

select id, FullName, Department,WorkDay from
(select *, (case WorkDay
                            WHEN 'MON' then 0 
                            WHEN 'TUE' then 1
                            WHEN 'WED' then 2 
                            WHEN 'THU' then 3 
                            WHEN 'FRI' then 4 END) as workdayno from Employees) d  order by  workdayno

now have to test rows in codebehind too.

Comment: same result. SQL editor shows correct order. but in codebehind; (in watch/locals window)rows array seems not sorted by workdays. and not ordered in psyhical inserted order either. is there any encoding settings in somewhere that I dont know in sqlite similar to mysql?

Comment: @KursatTurkay can you please try my second solution ...I edited my answer

Comment: really appreciated your effort Mr Pranay. you got amazing skills.
btw... tried your last linq faciliated modification. also modified model class too. But all WorkdayNo in row items seems null (debug/locals window). same result. maybe murpy rules exist right here ^^

Comment: @KursatTurkay - wait i ma giving you one more solution

Comment: at 1st sight, this still seems SQLite.Net-PCL weirdness (Universal Windows Platform) which I added via nuget.

Comment: @KursatTurkay - try out my new solution given in answer ..if there is any syntax error please reoslve it

Comment: public enum
and
from e in employees
worked.
ofsure I got a huge suspicious to SQLite.Net-PCL  library.

Comment: @KursatTurkay - ahh its finally worked so my effort not get wasted ...:)